# pip command in virtualenv ignored in favour of system pip command

Tags: python, linux, macos, virtualenv

I have created a virtualenv and activated it.  However, when I run `pip -V` I get this output:

```
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

One of the symptoms of this is that packages I install with pip are being put in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` instead of inside the virtualenv.

I checked the "shebang" line within the `bin/pip` script inside the virtualenv, and it points to the python interpreter within the virtualenv like it should.

`which pip` gives this output:

```
/home/alastair/Geekery/Courses/IT Masters/Configuration Management/venv-course/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to run `venv-course/bin/pip -V` I got this output:

```
venv-course/bin/pip: Command not found.
```

Yet the file is there and executable.  In my experience, this only happens when Linux, MacOS, etc. cannot interpret the shebang line at the start of the script, and so declares it unrunnable.

Turns out the problem was spaces in my directory names, which meant that the shebang line was this:

```
#!"/home/alastair/Geekery/Courses/IT Masters/Configuration Management/venv-course/bin/python2"
```

On Linux at least, quotes and spaces are not usable when specifying the name of a script interpreter.

I tried editing the shebang line as follows, but it still didn't work (and no, the leading space is not a problem):

```
#! /home/alastair/Geekery/Courses/IT\ Masters/Configuration\ Management/venv-course/bin/python2
```

### Solution

When I renamed the directories in the path to have underscores and then re-created the virtualenv, the shebang line was this:

```
#!/home/alastair/Geekery/Courses/IT_Masters/Configuration_Management/venv-course/bin/python2
```

This time, when I ran `pip -V` I get this output:

```
pip 1.5.6 from /home/alastair/Geekery/Courses/IT_Masters/Configuration_Management/venv-course/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```